# jQuery UI autocomplete select get all values from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

JSON has keys: id, n and d. I need to get the selected item's 'id' and 'n' in order to create an url.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "q.json",
    success: function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push(val);
      });

      $("#tags").autocomplete({ 
        maxResults: 4,
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request, response) {
          var filteredArray = $.map(items, function(item) {
            if (item.n.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
              return item.n + " ("+item.d+")";
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          });
          response(filteredArray.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
          alert("you selected " + ui.item.id);
          window.location.href = ui.item.id+"-"+ui.item.n;
        }
      });

    }
  });
```

How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: It's not very clear, what do you expect exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 3 keys in JSON and had to get them in select: function(event, ui)

```
      $("#tags").autocomplete({ 
          maxResults: 4,
          minLength: 2,
          source: function(request, response) {
            var filteredArray = $.map(items, function(item) {
              if (item.n.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
                return {
                  id: item.id
                  label: item.n + " ("+item.d+")",
                }
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            });
            response(filteredArray.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
          },
          select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
            window.location.href = ui.item.id+"-"+ui.item.n;
          },
        });

      });
```